# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT swift

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBAction func pressedButton(_ sender: Any) {result.text = "hello" + nameText.text!
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

версия xcode 11.2.1, изучаю по урокам 2018 года, подскажите, может быть проблема в синтаксисе или я где-то допустил ошибку? постоянно крашится приложение

> `(Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)`

Comment: Часто такая ошибка возникает из-за отсутствия связей между элементами на сториборде и их аутлетами или экшенами в коде (из-за вашей ошибки). Но точно можно ответить на этот вопрос, если посмотреть, то пишет Xcodeоб ошибке в консоли. Обычно там можно найти ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего был переименован IBOutlet. Перейди на сториборд, и проверь связи у всех элементов (последняя вкладка со значком в виде стрелки на правой панели), удали пустые, и протяни связи заново.